# Expressing a future desire using 'I wish' / 'I hope'

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Which sentences/s work [best] here?

Carl and Suzan are friends. They are just young kids now. Carl wants to be with Suzan throughout their youth too. Certainly, Carl is wishing for the future and something that is not certain; maybe one dies, maybe one moves house, etc. So he's not sure if he'll be able to be with Suzan, he only can wish so.

a) I wish I could be with Suzan in my youth.

b) I hope I will be with Suzan in my youth.

c) I wish I were with Suzan in my youth.

d) I wish to be with Suzan in my youth.

e) I hope to be with Suzan in my youth.

f) I wish Suzan would be with me in our youth.

Note that Carl's wish could possibly come true but is not certain to occur... and that it is out of his control.

Comment: 'In our youth' is almost always used retrospectively (or generically: 'In our youth, we tend to be idealists, not appreciating how hard people have to work in the background to prevent descent into chaos'. 'Throughout my teenage years' works here.

Comment: It's not *always* the case, but there's often a difference between ***wishing*** that things ***were*** different (note subjunctive ***were***, where we're talking about an "unreal present"), as opposed to ***hoping*** that things ***will be*** different (in some "not-yet-arrived" ***future***). You can't "hope things were different", and we don't usually speak of "wishing things will improve" in the future.

Comment: Here [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJcXRxy-nDU]  it says that for future we don't use 'wish' but 'hope. So I think B should be correct, right?

Comment: A child might say something like "I hope Suzan and I can still be together when we grow up" (assuming you mean 'in our youth' to mean 'as young adults').